# Why does "-e none" flag appear in my login?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

I get an error on pushing image to ECR:

> BuildError: {'errorDetail': {'message': 'denied: Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again.'}, 'error': 'denied: Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again.'}

I tried removing "-e none" from the response of :

```
aws ecr get-login --region <region_name>
```

Response :

> docker login -u AWS -p  -e none <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr..amazonaws.com

Why and from where does the "-e none" flag appear?

Answer (score 0):

`-e` flag is for email as per the docker documentation and is already depreciated. Since we don't use email with AWS ECR we generally use `-e none`

> --include-email | --no-include-email (boolean) Specify if the '-e' flag should be included in the 'docker login' command. The '-e' option
> has been deprecated and is removed in Docker version 17.06 and later.
> You must specify --no-include-email if you're using Docker version
> 17.06 or later. The default behavior is to include the '-e' flag in the 'docker login' output.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html

I hope it clears some confusions